# Swift auto layout in UICollectionView with intrinsic height of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm having a hard time with auto layout and UICollectionView. I have a vertical UICollectionVIewFlowLayout that contains two different types of cells, as in the image below:
[image]

The SingleCard cell contains a subview with an image (UIImageView). The HorizList cell contains a subview which is a horizontal UICollectionView (a list of thumbnail photos). The heights of the two cell types are as follows:

**SingleCard:** the width of the cell shall be the same as the screen width. *The height* shall be dynamic to the height of the UIImageView (to keep proportions of the image and have it fill screen width no matter of device size)

**HorizList:** the height is constant, say 200 points.

My attempt, in the CollectionViewController is to do

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...
   let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 235.0)
}
```

This I do to get the two cell's intrinsic size to apply. Then I do not implement

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

at all.

My question is, what do I implement in

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    ??
}
```

for the two different cell types? Maybe this is not the only thing I need to do, if so I'm grateful for additional hints.
Thanks!
/ola

Comment: Do you know your image proportions (sizes) before setting the images or is there a way you can calculate them?

Comment: Yes, I know the aspect ratio of the images.

Comment: Maybe try `return contentSize`